# Using oncontextmenu command is there any possibility to identify which menu has been selected on right click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any possibility to identify which menu has been selected on right click in an IE7 using the command oncontextmenu.

If yes can you please share the code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to report that this isn't possible. The clicks on the context menu are strictly secured, in the same way that clicks to the other menus on the browser are not traceable or interceptable by JavaScript.

Comment: thanks,
can we atleast disable any of those menus like i dont want the Export to Microsoft Excel option is it possible to disable. As i'm using it in an application i want it to be disabled for all my users.